# Parsing doubles and words in a string

Tags: c++, string, input

I was working on the following exercise from **The C++ Programming Language**:

> Read a sequence of possibly whitespace-separated (name,value) pairs,
>   where the name is a single whitespace-separated word and the value is
>   an integer or a floating-point value. Compute and print the sum and
>   mean for each name and the sum and mean for all names.

For example, given:

```
hello world5.678popcorn 8.123 rock 123 hello world 8.761 popcorn 98 rock 1.9rock2.3
```

The output of my implementation is:

```
rock: Sum (127.2), Mean (42.4)
hello world: Sum (14.439), Mean (7.2195)
popcorn: Sum (106.123), Mean (53.0615)
```

My implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<std::string, double> pairs;
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> occurences;

void save(const std::string& name, const std::string& value);
void trim(std::string& s, const std::string& chars = " ");

int main() {
    std::string line;
    getline(std::cin, line);

    std::string name;
    std::string value;

    bool name_saved;
    for(char c : line) {
        if(!name_saved && isdigit(c)) { // reached end of name
            name_saved = true;
            trim(name);
            value += c;
        } else if(!name_saved) { // add char to name
            name += c;
        } else if(name_saved) {
            if(isdigit(c) || (c == '.' && (value.find_first_of(".") == std::string::npos))) { // add char to value
                value += c;
            } else { // reached end of value
                trim(value);
                save(name, value);
                name = "";
                value = "";
                name_saved = false;

                if(isalpha(c)) {
                    name += c;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(value != "") {
        save(name, value);
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
    for(auto pair : pairs) {
        std::cout << pair.first << ": " << "Sum (" << pair.second << "), Mean (" << (pair.second / occurences[pair.first]) << ")\n";
    }

    return 0;
}

void save(const std::string& name, const std::string& value) {
    pairs[name] += std::stod(value);
    occurences[name]++;
}

void trim(std::string& s, const std::string& chars) {
    s.erase(0, s.find_first_not_of(chars));
    s.erase(s.find_last_not_of(chars) + 1);
}
```

I was wondering what would a more efficient approach to this exercise be? I feel that my code is quite messy and I would like to get some input on what I could use to clean it up and make it more compact.

Comment: Do you know how to use `std::istringstream`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No I do not. I will look into it thanks.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: A ```std::istringstream```` for extracting name and values will not work, because there is sometimes no white space between name and value. Or, I misunderstood your idea, and you meant a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many many different soultions. It depends a little bit on your personal programming style and what you have learned already or not.

The above example cries for "regular expressions". You can read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) in the Cpp- Reference about them. And especially the function [std::regex_search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) will be your friend.

First to the regurlar expression. You are looking for a "text" with embedded spaces ("single whitespace-separated word "), followed by a int or float. This can be expressed easily with a "regex":

```
([a-zA-Z]+ ?[a-zA-Z]+) ?(\d+\.?\d*)
```

So, first we have 1 or more alpha-characters, then an optional space and then again 1 or more alpha-characters. This makes up the name.

For the value, we have 1 or more digits, maybe followed by a "." and maybe more digits.

You get a better understanding, if you paste the regex and the test string in some online regex-tester like [this](https://regex101.com/).

It will give you some more detailed explanation. Espcially for the brackets "()", which form groups.

An the groups can be extracted after a `std::regex_search` has found a match. Meaning: If `std::regex_search` will find a match for the given regex, it will return true and the resulting groups can be found in `std::smatch`, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results) for a description.

And with all this, we can define a simple `for` loop to get all names and values from the test string.

```
for (std::string s{ test }; std::regex_search(s, sm, re); s = sm.suffix())
```

First we will initialize the "loop-run" variable, in this case a `std::string` and initialize it with the given test-string. Then we will search for a match in the test-string. If there was a match, then we will find the result in `sm[1]` and `sm[2]`. After we did all operations inside the loop body, we set the "loop-run" variable to the not yet matched rest of the test string. The suffix.

To goup, calculate and aggregate the values, we use a `std::map`. The key is the "name" and the value is a `std::pair` consisting of the count of names and the sum of the associated values. So, in the loop:

```
    for (std::string s{ test }; std::regex_search(s, sm, re); s = sm.suffix()) {

        // Count the occurences of a text
        aggregator[sm[1]].first++;

        // Sum up the values for a text
        aggregator[sm[1]].second += std::stod(sm[2]);
    }
```

we use `aggregator[sm[1]]` to create the name in or retrieve the name from map. In any case, we have then a reference to the current name entry, and we can increment the count and build the running sum.

This is a very simple 3 line approach, which does already nearly all the expected work.

The rest is simple calculation of expected sum and mean values and showing everything on the screen.

Please see the full code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

// The regex for words with embedded space and floats/ints
const std::regex re{ R"(([a-zA-Z]+ ?[a-zA-Z]+) ?(\d+\.?\d*))" };

int main() {

    // Definition Section --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // The input test string
    std::string test{"hello world5.678popcorn 8.123 rock 123 hello world 8.761 popcorn 98 rock 1.9rock2.3"};

    // Here we will store the result. The text and the associated "count" and "sum"
    std::map<std::string, std::pair<unsigned int, double>> aggregator{};
    std::smatch sm;


    // Find, store  and calculate data -------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Iterate though the string and get the text and the float value
    for (std::string s{ test }; std::regex_search(s, sm, re); s = sm.suffix()) {

        // Count the occurences of a text
        aggregator[sm[1]].first++;

        // Sum up the values for a text
        aggregator[sm[1]].second += std::stod(sm[2]);
    }


    // Output data ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Since the task is to calculate also the overall results, we will do 
    unsigned int countOverall{};
    double sumOverall{};

    // Iterate over the "text" data and output sum and mean value per text and aggregate the overall values
    for (const auto& [text, agg] : aggregator) { 

        // Output sum and mean per text
        std::cout << "\n" << text << ": Sum (" << agg.second << "), Mean (" << agg.second / agg.first << ")";

        // Aggregate overall values
        countOverall += agg.first;
        sumOverall += agg.second;
    }

    // Show overall result to the user.
    std::cout << "\n\nSum overall: (" << sumOverall << "), Mean overall: (" << sumOverall / countOverall << ")\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

If this solution is "better" or not? Please decide yourself . . .